# Video is not playing in intel xdk

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I am  developing hybrid application by using intel xdk and jquery mobile for UI, i am trying to play video in my intel xdk project but it is not playing, i am referring this sample http://qnimate.com/playing-videos-in-intel-xdk-app/   if i click play button nothing will happen even  i added player plugin in my project

i am using this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <style>
        @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }                          
        @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
        @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }                                    
        @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
    </style>

    <script src="lib/ft/fastclick.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="playVideo();">Play Video</button>

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>        
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>          
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>              

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init-dev.js"></script>

    <script>
        function playVideo()
        {
            //this function launches default video player and plays the video.mp4 file.
            intel.xdk.player.playPodcast("http://labs.qnimate.com/video.mp4");
        }

        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.player.podcast.start", function(){
            //started playing video
            alert("start");

        }, false);

        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.player.podcast.stop", function(){
            //video finished or player closed
            alert("stop");
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.player.podcast.error", function(){
            //error occured therefore video cannot be played
            alert("error");
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.player.podcast.busy", function(){
            //another video is already being played
            alert("busy");
        }, false);    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me what is the problem?

Comment: Are you including the necessary plugins as part of your project?

Comment: @xmnboy i added player plugin in my project, what else we need to include?

Comment: I did a debug trace and it appears to be going into the plugin and calling the right stuff, but I cannot quickly debug the native code. My guess is there may be something wrong with the plugin. I'll ask the responsible engineer to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The `playPodcast()` function is only supported in the legacy container, which is going away. The Cordova version of these APIs does not include that method, so it is, effectively, no longer available.

Comment: Then how to play videos for cordova version?

Comment: Search for "play video cordova phonegap" for a variety of options, including the `<video>` tag and several video player plugins. If you choose to use the `<video>` tag I highly recommend you use Crosswalk and test using the Debug tab, since that uses Crosswalk. Using the native Android webview will not work well.